Hartshorne Exercise IV.1.10: making sure a point is nonsingular.
Hartshorne's exercise IV.$1.10$ reads as follows:

Let $X$ be an integral projective scheme of dimension $1$ over $k$ algebraically closed, which is locally complete intersection, and has genus $g=1$. Fix a point $P_0 \in X_{reg}$ (the subset of closed nonsingular points of $X$). Show that the map $$X \mapsto \mathcal{L}(P-P_0)$$ gives a one-to-one correspondance between the points of $X_{reg}$ and the elements of $\rm{Pic}^0(X)$.

The result is already known if $X$ is nonsingular, so I'll assume the opposite. There is a slight detail missing in my solution, and I couldn't find any resource which filled this gap: I cannot show that the points $P$ I find lie in $X_{reg}$. Here is how it goes.
Exercise $1.9$ just before ensures two things:

every Cartier divisor / invertible sheaf on $X$ is linearly equivalent to one with support in $X_{reg}$ (and hence can be expressed as a Weil divisor, for which the degree map makes sense, therefore $\rm{Pic}^0(X)$ is well defined),
$X$ has a dualizing sheaf $\omega_X^{\circ}$, which gives rise to $K$ a canonical divisor with support in $X_{reg}$, and makes Riemann-Roch work again: $$l(D) - l(K-D) = \deg(D)+1-g$$
where all divisors are represented by ones with support in $X_{reg}$.

From this, there is no challenge in copying Example $1.3.7$ which shows the result for elliptic curves. Namely, given any divisor of degree $0$ on $X_{reg}$, we can show that $l(D+P_0) = 1$. In other words, there is a unique Cartier divisor $D'$ on $X$ linearly equivalent to $D+P_0$, and it is easy to see that the support of $D'$ is in a single point $P\in X$. Moreover, if that point lies in $X_{reg}$, its multiplicity as a Weil divisor is $1$ (because $\deg(D') = \deg(D+P_0)$) and we are done.
My question is: how do we know that $P \in X_{reg}$ ?
I attempted to use the normalization $\tilde{X}$, which has genus $0$ (Exercise $1.8$) and hence $\tilde{X} \cong \mathbb{P}^1$ (also implying $X$ has a single nonsingular point), and work by contradiction using the local rings. I got a few things, but not the expected result so far, as this post is already getting quite long I spare you the details for now. Is there by any chance an easy argument I might have missed?

You only need to show that if $P$ is not a regular point, then $\mathcal{L}(P)$ is not Cartier. Think about this: if it is Cartier, what is the pullback of it on $\tilde X$? Then what is the pullback of $\mathcal{L}(P-P_0)$?

@ChenJiang It not a contradiction with your argument, but it seems that the singular point is still $\mathbb{Q}$-Cartier. Is there a geometric explanation to this special case ?

@ChenJiang Assuming $P$ is the image of $0 \in \mathbb{P}^1$, then its pullback is Cartier, locally expressed by an element of the local ring $k[t]_{(t)}$, of valuation $1$ (so as to ensure that $D + P_0 - P$ is pulled back to a degree $0$ divisor). I wanted to show that this "unramified" situation is impossible if $P$ has only one pre-image, but I couln't make any progress. For instance, the cubic nodal has two pre-images of the singular point, and for each the morphism is unramified, whereas for the cubic cuspidal, a single point lies above $P$, but the local morphism is ramified.

@ChenJiang Am I interpreting your advice in the correct direction ?

more or less you are in the correct direction. The point is that if $\mathcal{L}(P)$ is Cartier, then its pullback should have bigger degree (the ramification degree), so that the pullback of $\mathcal{L}(P-P_0)$ can not be of degree $0$

@ChristopherNicol in this case $P$ is not defined by a local function, but $mP$ is defined by a local function. The geometric explanation is that whenever you cut $X$ by a hyperplane through $P$, the intersection always has higher multiplicity along $P$.

@ChenJiang I did arrive at that conclusion, but I couln't prove it in the general case (which is why I made this post). Would you have any tip ? Sorry to bother you with this.

Nice question, apologies about the delay in answering it.
Let $Q\in X$ be a non-regular point, let $\nu:\widetilde{X}\to X$ be the normalization map, let $\mathcal{L}\in \operatorname{Pic}^0(X)$, and suppose $\mathcal{L}\cong \mathcal{O}_X(Q-P_0)$. Two cases:

$Q$ has more than one preimage, say $Q_1,\cdots,Q_n$. Then any rational function with a zero/pole at $Q$ must have one at each of the preimages of $Q$, so $\nu^*\mathcal{O}_X(Q-P_0)\cong \mathcal{O}_{\widetilde{X}}(c_1Q_1+\cdots+c_nQ_n-P_0)$ for $c_i>0$ and hence $\deg \nu^*\mathcal{O}_X(Q-P_0)>0$. But this doesn't match the fact that if we pick a Cartier divisor with support in $X_{reg}$, the pullback of that is degree zero.

$Q$ has exactly one preimage, say $\widetilde{Q}$. Then the injective map of local rings $\mathcal{O}_{X,Q}\to \mathcal{O}_{\widetilde{X},\widetilde{Q}}$ must send $\mathfrak{m}_Q$ in to $\mathfrak{m}_{\widetilde{Q}}^2$. Proof: if not, this would give us $\mathfrak{m}_{Q}\to\mathfrak{m}_{\widetilde{Q}}/\mathfrak{m}_{\widetilde{Q}}^2$ is surjective. Combining that with the fact that $\mathcal{O}_{\widetilde{X},\widetilde{Q}}$ is a finitely-generated $\mathcal{O}_{X,Q}$-module (as normalization for varieties is finite) and $k(Q)=k(\widetilde{Q})=k$ since they're closed points in a scheme of finite type over an algebraically closed field, we would satisfy the conditions of lemma II.7.4 and $\mathcal{O}_{X,Q}\to \mathcal{O}_{\widetilde{X},\widetilde{Q}}$ would be surjective, hence an isomorphism, which is a contradiction. Therefore again we would have $\deg \nu^*\mathcal{O}_X(Q-P_0)>0$, which is just as impossible this time as in case 1.



Thank you very much for your answer !
